# What happens to new requests if python webserver has no free workers?

Tags: sockets, networking, tcp, asgi

If a 1-worker uvicorn server (run on linux) is locked by a CPU-bound task what happens to new requests?

Are they queued between client and server inside TCP connects?

Will they be later (when server is unlocked) processed in order they were sent? What component is responsible for this order if any?

Can the requests be lost for any reasons other than timeout set on client side or lost connection? Is there any resource other than memory that can be overflowed by incoming requests?

I understand that locking an ASGI server is a terrible design. The example is for the purposes of understanding of the request flow.

Comment: Don't know, but most servers have a queue because most operating systems have a queue.